# Casting a negative int to a bigger unsigned int in C

Tags: c

```
int main(){
 int a = -33553454;
 unsigned long b = a;
 return 0;
}
```

In the above example, `a` is first sign extend to a 64 bit value as a `signed` integer (meaning 1's will be placed on its left side), and the value is then assigned to `b` as an unsigned int.

Is it safe to say that, only the type of the original source operand matters (if its signed or unsigned) and the destination type is not taken into account in this case (since the destination is unsigned, you would think `a` would not get sign extended because the end result is unsigned anyways, and 0s would fill the left side of `b`. )

Comment: Have you compile this with the warnings?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean with *"the destination type is not taken into account in this case"*.

Comment: What you're describing at first is just how two's complement notation works.

Comment: I mean the destination is unsigned, you would think `a` would not get sign extended because the  end result is unsigned anyways, and 0s would fill the left side of `b`.

Answer (score 4):

You're converting an `int` value to an `unsigned long` value.  How this happens is dictated by section 6.3.1.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
> type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than
> the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
> until the value is in the range of the new type.
>
> *3* Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined
> or an implementation-defined signal is raised

Paragraph 2 is what applies in this case.  Because the value in question is negative and therefore out of the range of an `unsigned long`, the largest value for that type +1 is added to the original value to get the new value.

So assuming the maximum value for `unsigned long` is 2<sup>64</sup>-1 (or 18446744073709551615) the value -33553454 (0xFE0003D2) is converted to 18446744073709551616 - 33553454 = 18446744073675998162 (0xFFFFFFFFFE0003D2).  You'll notice that if your machine uses two's complement representation (which most do) that the representation of these numbers happens to be the same (after sign extension).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example, made it more clear. Not sure who writes these C documentations, they couldn't have explained it in a more confusing way.

Comment: They could have just sign extend the source value, then assign the result to the unsigned result value, it would be simpler to explain? it's like doing `unsigned int a = -12`, -12 is signed extend to int then the result is assigned to `a`.

Comment: Language specifications are written for compiler writers, not ordinary programmers.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Good language specifications are written to be precise (as limited by other goals), which is needed both by compiler writers and by good programmers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Sure, but writing a program in a language doesn't require the specification like writing a compiler does, and language specifications are notoriously programmer-unfriendly.